# Find min cost from node A to node B and also keep the path info

Tags: algorithm

I got a question which is to find the min cost from the least number node (1) to the largest number node (7).

The cost is the edge between nodes. I labeled them.

This problem got me to think of the Dijkstra which leads the time complexity for `O((v+e) log v)`

Any other better approach to solving this question efficiently?

The other requirement is to keep the path information, any thought to keep the path?

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what Dijkstra's algorithm is for. If it weren't the best way, you would know. :-)

Comment: Bidirectional Dijkstra might be faster in practice since you reduce the number of nodes to visit. It has the same theoretical complexity, though.

Comment: bfs  algorithm  would help

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, the complexity is as you say and cannot be better.  As @nico-schertler commented, searching from both sides in parallel (or taking turns) and stopping as soon as something touches is faster than doing just a search from one side, but it will have the same complexity.  It is possible in this case (with fixed costs for the bidirectional edges) but it needs not be in the general case (e. g. cost depending on the already taken path) where Dijkstra is still applicable.

Concerning the keeping of the path:  Of course, the whole thing often only makes sense if you get the path to be taken as an answer.  There are two main approaches to get the path as a result.

One is to store the path already taken to a certain node along with the node in the lists (white/grey in the classical implementation).  Each time you add a new node, you extend the path of its former node by one step.  If you find the target node, you can directly return the path as a result (along with the cost sum).  Of course this way means uses a lot of memory.

The other is to not store the origin node along with each new found node, so each node points to the node it was visited from first.  Think of it as putting up signposts in each node how to go back.  This way, if you find the target node, you will have to go backwards from each node to the one it was first visited from and build the path in reverse order in the process.  Then you can return this path.